# Reactivesearch, Datasearch component: Is there a way to extend the component on SearchIconClick?

Tags: handler, reactivesearch

I would like to extend the Datasearch component by a function that reacts on the event that the search icon is clicked. In https://github.com/appbaseio/reactivesearch/pull/747/files there is a handler for this, called handleSearchIconClick. However, it seems that this handler can't be overwritten. Is there another way to react in a meaningful way on this event? If yes, are there examples around that help to solve this problem? Thank's in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have a custom click event with custom search icon, here is a sample which demonstrates that

https://codesandbox.io/s/datasearch-igd89

Comment: Very nice! I should have found out myself, reading the docs more carefully. The "icon" is mentioned there and it is also tagged with jsx indicating that there may be more about it than just displaying a custom icon. Thanks a lot!